# How to use AWK to enclose fields with commas in quotation marks?

Tags: regex, unix, awk

Suppose I have this file delimited by tabs:

```
This    is    a    cat,dog
I    run    around    the    house,garage
```

I want to replace all instances of tabs with commas (I can do that part), but also wrap all words with commas in them in quotation marks. So the resulting file would look like:

```
This,is,a,"cat,dog"
I,run,around,the,"house,garage"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This works for sed (not awk obviously): `sed -r 's|(\w+,\w+(,\w+)*)|\"\1\"|g' text.txt | sed -r 's|\s+|,|g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /,/) $i = "\"" $i "\"" } 1'
```

Output:

```
This,is,a,"cat,dog"
I,run,around,the,"house,garage"
```

#### Explanation:

- `OFS=,` and `$1=$1` makes awk replace FS with OFS.
- The for loop checks each field and encloses it in double-quotes if it contains a comma.
- The `1` at the end invokes the default rule `{ print $0 }`.

#### Edit

[*steve*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13851031/1331399) is right, sed is briefer in this case. You could make it a bit shorter by using a regex (borrowed from steve) and appending the setting of OFS and FS (tested with GNU awk):

```
awk '{ $0 = gensub(/[^\t]*,[^\t]*/, "\"&\"", "g"); $1=$1 } 1' FS='\t' OFS=,
```

Comment: This works, but if there are spaces between the words with commas in them, I don't get the desired result. :/ I want to replace tabs with commas, and surround all fields separated by delimeters (tabs) that have commas in them with quotation marks. Sorry if I wasn't originally more clear

Answer (score 1):

Using sed and tr, also handles spaces between words:

```
 sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]*[ ]*,[ ]*[a-zA-Z]*\)/"\1"/' input | tr '\t' ','
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is probably not the right tool for this job. I think `sed` would be a better option. Here's what I'd do:

```
sed 's/[^\t]*,[^\t]*/"&"/g;s/\t/,/g' file
```